# How does one eliminate Objective-C @try @catch blocks like this?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a developer from Python world used to using exceptions. I found in many places that using exceptions is not so wise here, and did my best to convert to NSErrors when needed. but then I encounter this:

```
NSMutableArray *results;
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicts)
{
    // Memory management code omitted
    SomeModel *model = [[SomeModel alloc] init];
    model.attr1 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key1"] integerValue];
    model.attr2 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key2"] integerValue];
    model.attr3 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key3"] integerValue];
    model.attr4 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key4"] integerValue];

    [results addObject:model];
}
```

with some of the objects in dict containing NSNull, which would result an "unrecognized selector" exception. In that case, I want to drop that datum completely. My first instinct is to wrap the whole content of the for block into a @try-@catch block:

```
NSMutableArray *results;
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicts)
{
    @try
    {
        SomeModel *model = [[SomeModel alloc] init];
        model.attr1 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key1"] integerValue];
        model.attr2 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key2"] integerValue];
        model.attr3 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key3"] integerValue];
        model.attr4 = [[dict objectForKey:@"key4"] integerValue];

        [results addObject:model];
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But is this a good approach? I can't come up with a solution without repeating checks on each variable, which is really ugly IMO. Hopefully there are alternatives to this that haven't occur to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basic rule to Objective-C is that `@try/catch` means your program is going to crash, and will not continue to execute.

Comment: If with "that datum" you mean: the entire SomeModel object, then your approach with the try-catch is fine. There is no rule against using try-catch. If with "the datum" you mean: that particular attribute of SomeModel, then jaydee3's answer gives you a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people use a category on NSDictionary for these cases:

```
- (id)safeObjectForKey:(id)aKey
{
  id obj = [self objectForKey:aKey];
  if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
  {
    return nil;
  }

  return obj;
}
```

You still need to make sure, that your dict is an actual dictionary instance.

Comment: Why do you specifically check for `NSNull`? This doesn't seem to solve the problem...

Comment: That's exactly what was asked for. That's a common problem after parsing JSON. You can send any message on a `nil` object, but not on a `NSNull` object. The crash occurs with the call of `integerValue` in his case. It will not crash, if nil is returned instead.

Comment: But in this case, should you not check for `if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])` instead?

Comment: The general problem is that you get `NSNull` objects. You cannot call anything on them. Normally you expect a specific type from any API. And you want the actual data, or nil, if there is no data. NSNull is a third case, that you don't need to handle, if you use this category. Of course, it would be even better to check every type you expect like in your example. But this is a more general approach that is enough in most cases.

Comment: Wow so this is a common problem I guess, since I didn't even mention I was parsing in my post. This does not solve my problem completely because my main appeal is to have an easy way to _drop_ the erroneous datum, but I guess this is OK if we look at our data in a different way. I'll mark this one as correct if nothing better shows up.

Comment: you have to check that afterwards. e.g. give your model a method `-(BOOL)isValid` and check, if all values are non nil? Than in your code above only add the object to the results, if isValid returns YES.

Comment: I may not be obvious that this approach will result in 0 being assigned to the attribute, rather than the attribute not being assigned at all. Sending the "integerValue" message to a nil value will result in the default integer value, that is: 0.

Answer (score 3):

The proper Objective-C way to do this would be:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dicts)
{
    if (! [dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        continue;
    // ...
}
```

Testing if a receiver can respond to a message before sending it is a typical pattern in Objective-C.

Also, take note that exceptions in Objective-C are always a programmer error and are not used for normal execution flow.

Comment: I realize that using exceptions here is probably not a good idea, but am I really left with no other choices than checking every one of my entries?

Comment: I believe the requirement is to handle dictionary entries that are `NSNull`, not the entire dictionary.

Comment: @janusfidel All of Apple's code is so optimized that it runs in `O(0)`. Except if they decide that a device is no longer supported, in that case they make it run in `O(n!!)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to solve the problem using KVC. Something like this:

```
- (id)initWithPropertyDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
                     lookUpTable:(NSDictionary *)keyToProperty
{
    self = [self init];
    for (NSString *key in dict)
    {
        NSString *propertyName;
        if ([keyToProperty objectForKey:key])
            propertyName = [keyToProperty objectForKey:key];
        else
            propertyName = key;
        if ([[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:propertyName];
        }
    }
}
```

The setback of this resolution is that I'll have to use NSNumber for my properties, but for JSON data there is really no distinction between floating numbers and integers, so this is fine.

And if you really want primitive types, you can couple this method with custom setters that converts those NSNumbers into appropriate types.

With this, all you need to do is check for nil before adding the object into the array. Much cleaner everywhere except the model class.

Thanks to jaydee3 for inspiring me to focus on changing the model class.